# Android BLE scanning sporadically doesn't work

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ibeacon

I tried this both on Android 4.4 and Android 5.1 phones and SDKs and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
I have a background service that continuously does BLE scanning for beacons.

1) However, after few hours BLE scanning dies silently (though bluetooth is still turned on my phone).

2) Often, when my app starts, it just will not do any scanning until I restart the app

3)I have a timer in my app that wakes up every 1 minute. It stops and starts the scanning, if the last received scanrecord is more than 2 minutes. But this alternative (and ugly fix) rarely works

Now , I am out of options in making the scans work continuously.

Has anyone observed such random behavior in scanning? How to address this issue?

On Android 5.1(SDK 21), I used BluetoothLeScanner for scanning. On Android 4.4 (SDK 4.4), I used BluetoothAdapter for scanning. I noticed above issues 1,2,3 on both 4.4 and 5.1 using Nexus 5

What am I doing  wrong?

Comment: Is your service running in "foreground mode"? Else you have the risk that your process is being killed by the Android system.

Comment: No. How would I do that?

Comment: Check out https://www.google.se/search?q=android%20foreground%20service